# JwtSecurityTokenHandler reference is unknown on tfs

Tags: c#, tfs

I'm using the package NuGet `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt` for a project.

It works well in production and during our test but failed on each TFS Build with the code:

> The type or namespace name 'JwtSecurityTokenHandler' doesn't exist in
>   namespace 'System.ItentityModel.Tokens'

An other package is necessary? What can I do to solve this?

Comment: What is your build definition? do you have nuget restore?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk Yes. It works fine for other package.

Comment: In the NuGet restore log, can you see the `System.IdentityModel.Tokens` downloaded correctly?  (in the correct version)

Comment: How can I retrieve this log for a TFS Build ? Where is it stored?

Comment: Which TFS version do you use? you can find the log in the Summary page, in the left side you can click on the build steps and see the logs.

Comment: In the log I see every package except for this one ! How can I correct this ?

Comment: check the `packages.config` if it contains this NuGet.

Comment: This NuGet already is in the package.config : `<package id="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" version="4.0.4.403061554" targetFramework="net45" />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolve the problem by adding manually the DDL in the project and a reference to it...